# Get IP address from python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ip

I'm trying to get the ip address associated with network interface without spawning additional processes in Linux:

```
def get_ip_address(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
        s.fileno(), 0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
        struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15].encode('utf-8'))
        )[20:24])
```

But always getting this error:

```
struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15].encode('utf-8'))
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I get this error message when my interface is not assigned an IP address. which interface do you test and what does `/sbin/ifconfig -a` report ?

Comment: What result do you want if the interface has no IP address?

Answer (score 3):

Translate host to ip :

```
import socket
print (socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
```

To get host by name :

```
import socket
print (socket.gethostbyname("www.goole.com"))
```

Comment: And what if I have multiple network interfaces without any internet connection?

Comment: the first comment returns `127.0.0.1` ....

Comment: It always returns the output as '127.0.0.1'. But I need both public and private IP addresses.

Comment: Do you have a working internet connection?